# laravel print a view without displaying it in browser

Tags: php, laravel, printing

in my laravel project i need to take print out of a doctor's prescription. and for that i have already created the header part and saved in database. when the user clicks on the printer icon next to a div then the content inside that div needs to be printed with the saved header.

the method is used is: in the view part which contain the printer icon

```
<div class="AnswerBlock"><div class="NmaeDate">
            <span class="name"><?php echo 'Prescription :'; ?></span><span style="float:right;"><a href="<?php echo URL::to('/user/print-prescription',array($id,1));?>"><img src="<?php echo asset('images/footericons/printout.png'); ?>" title="prescription1" alt="take print" width="20" height="20"></a></span>

                   <div class="answer">
                       <?php echo stripslashes($data1->prescription1);?>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

in the user controller:

```
public function anyPrintPrescription($eid='',$no=''){

            $drpres='';
      $prs = DB::table('appoint')->where('id','=',$eid)->first();
      if($no=='1'){
       $drpres = $prs->prescription1;     
      }
      elseif($no=='2'){
          $drpres= $prs->prescription2;
      }
      elseif($no=='3'){
          $drpres = $prs->prescription3;
      }
      $presheader = Admin::where('id','=',$prs->d_id)->pluck('prescription_header');
      return View::make('con.printout_prescription')->with(array('presc'=>$drpres,'phead'=>$presheader));  

   }
```

and the view is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
.print:last-child {
 page-break-after: auto;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
<div class="print"><?php echo $phead;?></div>
<div class="print"><?php echo $presc;?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output i'm getting is : when the print icon is clicked the printer option prompt window is opening. but at the same time the browser goes to the view url and displays it.

Is anyone knows how to make the window not displaying the view ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Laravel or even a PHP question, it's a matter of what you can and can't do with a browser.

A browser can't print something without viewing it.  The only thing that I can suggest is to open the view in a new window or tab (change the code that calls back to the view) and have it close after the print is done.

Comment: Ok.. thank you for your suggestion. i have implemented it using window.onfocus and worked